# how to use "Type Hints - PEP 484" when creating new objects in python 3.7 to be able code completion in pycharm 2019.2.4

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, hashlib

system: fedora 31

Pycharm doesn't get me auto completion when type `my_var_hash.` , there is no problem with venv.

**How use** Type-Hints with modules like hashlib and that way can we use auto complete options (CTRL+space).
Example of code bellow but auto completion doesn't work.(functions: `my_var_hash.update(b'lmao') , my_var_hash.hexdigest()` ).

```
import hashlib

my_var_hash = hashlib.sha256()
print(my_var_hash)
my_var_hash.update(b'lmao')
print(my_var_hash.hexdigest())
print(type(my_var_hash.hexdigest()))
```

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `hashlib.sha256()` does not have type defined or some docstring (when using standard cptyhon)
PyCharm therefore assigns it the "Any" type that does not have any extra info

This is a library issue, not a problem with your setup

Comment: then, is impossible to achieve what I desire?

Comment: the module/library would be rewritten and adding type annotations, that's what are you saying?

Comment: yes, you would have to add type hints or docstrings with types, someone might do it in the future -> even you can do it as python accepts contributions from the community https://devguide.python.org/ this is a great point where to start (in code documentation is very likely to be accepted if done in a good way compared to functionality changes) you can look at other built in libraries to see how it is done there